# How to push value of LiveData more than once?

Tags: android, reactive-programming, android-livedata

I have a `MutableLiveData` in my `viewModel`.  I set value for this `liveData`   with a response of the server. But sometimes I need to push the current value of this liveData again. To achieve this I'm doing something like this:

```
    _prepareAdminMenu.value = _prepareAdminMenu.value
```

I want to know that is there a better way than this?

Comment: why do you need to do that?

Comment: @TimCastelijns In my application, I have some situations that my fragment should be reset, So I prefer to use my last value in viewModel, instead to fire another request to the server. because of that, I need to set the value of live data again to set my views in the fragment